# Restart service from bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo, systemd, services

I'm trying to restart a service `myservice` from a service that is run as a daemon.

I've created a file called `myapprestart` in `/etc/sudoers.d/`
that looks like this

```
%myuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart myservice
%myuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start myservice
%myuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl stop myservice
```

The `myapprestart.service` daemon is running successfully as a timed unit that calls `/home/myuser/restart.sh` but always fails with the following line in journalctl

```
failed to stop myservice.service: Interactive authentication required.
```

the script file`/home/myuser/restart.sh` contains lines like below

```
systemctl stop myservice
systemctl start myservice
```

I need some pointers on what i'm not doing right. I've looked at at least four similar questions, but for some reason this case seems not to work. I'm using ubuntu 19.02.

Comment: you need to run your script with `sudo` permission, like that : `sudo /home/myuser/restart.sh`

Comment: @damadam I'm pretty sure that's the answer--would you be willing to post it (or something like it) as one?

Comment: @EliahKagan depends if OP want something that could be automatic or not

Comment: If you need to restart a service that has stopped or crashed, use the proper systemd tools. The 'restart' stanza in the .service file, or a systemd timer, etc.

Comment: @damdam can I use sudo in systemd?

Comment: Does your service need to be run by root? If not, you could run it as a user service, forgoing the need for sudo.

Comment: I finally solved the problem, the summary is that i needed to call the command with sudo, so i had to update my ExecStart to `/usr/bin/sudo /home/myuser/restart.sh`

Comment: @jidexl21 you ping me wrong, so I didn't see your comment, my username is dam**a**dam ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script `restart.sh` use the `systemctl` command, which is part of systemd; because this command needs root rights due to his role, you need to use the `sudo` command to be able to use it (and your user must be refered in `sudoers` as an authorized sudo user). Your command would be like below :

```
sudo /home/myuser/restart.sh
```

- `/home/myuser/restart.sh` is just the absolute path to start the script, which is the same thing as doing `sudo ./restart.sh` inside `/home/myuser/` folder

Also, as [OP mentionned it in comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193811/restart-service-from-bash-script#comment1998894_1193811), you can also call `sudo` with absolute path with `/usr/bin/sudo` (`/usr/bin/sudo apt update` is the same as `sudo apt update`)

Comment: I also noted that even in a case where the command is whitelisted with nopass in the sudoers.d if called from a variable in the script like `systemctl stop $unit` where unit is `myservice` it fails